# Node.js: Where To Place Internal Modules In Folder Structure?

Tags: node.js, npm, directory-structure, node-modules

### The Situation

I often see Node.js applications with the following structure:

*Common pattern:*

- `lib/` or `src/` - the self-written code

  - `index.js` - main code
  - *internal modules*... (e.g. self-written for this project)
- `node_modules`

  - *external modules*... (e.g. taken from another project)
- `package.json`

### My Problem

What I don't like about this pattern:

- I **don't feel comfortable** about it because you have to **explicitly specify the directory path** of the internal modules when `require()`ing:

  ```
  // /lib/index.js

  var internalMod = require('./internal'); // `require('internal')` (without path) wouldn't work
  internalMod.doSomething();
  ```

### My Idea

So I think it would be a good idea also to **place internal modules in an `node_modules` folder (somewhere** in the project). So `node` would be able to find them, even if you don't explicitly specify the path.

*For example:*

- `src/` - the self-written code

  - `index.js` - main code
  - `node-modules` - for internals

    - *internal modules*...
- `node_modules` - for externals

  - *external modules*... (e.g. taken from another project)
- `package.json`

### My Question

1. **Are there any cons about my plan?**
2. **Is there another idea where to place internal modules in folder structure?**

Thanks for your answer (or comment). - If anything is unclear, please comment.

Comment: What's the motivation behind having internal modules? Why not just make them external? With external modules this problem goes away and you get to re-use the module in other projects.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Concerning your question: It's not possible to reuse any module. Some modules are really tight to the "parent module" with nothing then **dependencies** in order to solve a very specific problem (maybe by using more abstract, external modules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `npm link` to pull your modules into node_modules?
See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link